# java.io.EOFException when sending serialized data to a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, urlconnection

I'm tring to upload from my Java local application an object that will include a file to a server. My plan is that a servlet running on tomcat will get the object using the `ObjectInputStream` in the `doGet` method. But I get an `EOFE`xception`.

Here is the client code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\rafi.txt");
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int n = 0;
        while (-1 != (n = inputStream.read(buffer))) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        File2 c2 = new File2(buffer);
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/servertest/Server");
        URLConnection cnx = url.openConnection();
        cnx.setDoInput(true);
        cnx.setDoOutput(true);
        cnx.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        InputStream in = cnx.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = cnx.getOutputStream();
        cnx.connect();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        oos.writeObject(c2);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        boolean readBoolean = ois.readBoolean();
        System.out.println(readBoolean);
        ois.close();
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

here is the server's servlet

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
@WebServlet("/Server")
public class Server extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Server() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        InputStream in = req.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);

        File2 data_in;
        try {
            data_in = (File2) ois.readObject();
            byte[] a = new byte[data_in.mybytearray.length];
            System.arraycopy(data_in.mybytearray, 0, a, 0,data_in.mybytearray.length);
            System.out.println(a.toString());
            oos.writeBoolean(true);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            oos.writeBoolean(false);
        }
        finally{
            oos.close();
            }

        res.setContentType("java-internal/" + File2.class.getName());
        in.close();
    }
}
```

When I debug the server side and run the client I get the exception in this row

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
```

This is the error I get

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [test1.Server] in context with path [/servertest] threw exception
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at test1.Server.doGet(Server.java:38)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817360/eofexception-when-reading-serialized-object-in-servlet), but i't didn't help me. I'm using tomcat 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InputStream in = cnx.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = cnx.getOutputStream();
```

The `URLConnection#getInputStream()` will immediately send the HTTP request to the server in order to retrieve the response body. The way as you've written the code, this thus takes place *before* you've written any bit to the HTTP request body. Hence the `EOFException` on the server side.

You need to ask for the HTTP response body by `URLConnection#getInputStream()` **after** you've written the necessary data to the HTTP request body. Here's a rewrite:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://localhost:8080/servertest/Server").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(c2);
oos.close();

ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
boolean readBoolean = ois.readBoolean();
ois.close();

System.out.println(readBoolean);
```

Also, since you're basically sending a HTTP POST request, you need to handle this in the servlet's `doPost()` method rather than the `doGet()` method.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: this isn't really the best way of sending files over HTTP. While it might work, this is very tight coupled to Java serialization mechanism. I'd suggest to send HTTP `multipart/form-data` requests instead. This can be achieved by [Apache HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) on the client side and [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) on the server side. This way the servlet is reuseable for other purposes, such as a HTML form with `<input type="file">` in the front. Also the client can this way be reused to upload files to other HTTP websites.

Comment: ok i'l check those apache packs. 
btw where did the connect command disappeared?
i tried adding it in a few places and i got
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)

Comment: You do not need it. You were also firing it too early. The `getInputStream()` will already implicitly run the `connect()` at the right moment. Just use the code exactly as in my answer. In your original client code, you need to replace `URL url` all the way up to `out.close()` with this piece. It's all exactly what you need and already in the right order.

Comment: To learn more about using `URLConnection`, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Answer (score 1):

I solved this pbm with on client side :

```
HttpURLConnection cnx = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost:8080/web").openConnection();
cnx.setRequestMethod("PUT");
```