# eofexception while setting up stream

Tags: java, servlets, eofexception

I'm trying to send a string to the servlet from java program and retrieve the same string with some padding.
Here's the code i'm working on and the problem is `java.io.EOFException` is being thrown at the establishment of inputstream in java program.
why does the end of stream is occuring when i'm setting it up. please clarify my doubt.

Servlet program is

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class ProgServlet implements Servlet {
public void init(ServletConfig sc){
}
public void service (ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, java.io.IOException
{

}
public void destroy(){

}
public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public String getServletInfo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("doPost");
    //Setting up streams
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    String p = "Server String";
    //Receiving data from client and resends by padding
    try {
        p =  (String) ois.readObject();
        p = p.concat(" -sever padding");
        oos.writeObject(p);
        oos.flush();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
    }

}
```

}

java program on client is

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Enter a string :");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String data = s.next();
    s.close();
    URL serv = null;
    try {
        serv = new URL("http://10.0.0.9:8080/project/projectservlet");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpURLConnection servletConnection = null;
    System.out.println("establishing communication with server....");
    try {
        servletConnection = (HttpURLConnection) serv.openConnection();
        System.out.println("connection with the server established"+servletConnection.getRequestMethod());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        servletConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(""+servletConnection.getRequestMethod());
    servletConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    servletConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

    System.out.println("setting up streams to communicate...");
    ObjectOutputStream dos = null;
    ObjectInputStream dis = null;
    try {
        dos = new ObjectOutputStream(servletConnection.getOutputStream());


        System.out.println("Streams are up and ready to go");
        System.out.println("Sending data to the server...");
        dos.flush();
        dos.writeObject(data);
         dos.flush();
         System.out.println("Data sent successfullyy \n Retrieving data from server");
         dis = new ObjectInputStream(servletConnection.getInputStream());
         data = (String) dis.readObject();
         System.out.println("Data retrieved from the server is "+data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        dos.close();
        dis.close();
        servletConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

the output and stack trace is

`Enter a string :
jaggu

establishing communication with server....

connection with the server established

GET

POST

setting up streams to communicate...

Streams are up and ready to go

Sending data to the server...

Data sent successfully

 Retrieving data from server

    java.io.EOFException

    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)

    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)

    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)

    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)

    at ServletInvokation.main(ServletInvokation.java:57)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    at ServletInvokation.main(ServletInvokation.java:69)`

Answer (score 1):

In the java client, the output stream represents the request sent to the server, and the input stream represents the response retrieved from the server. When you call `servletConnection.getInputStream()`, you are requesting the response from the server, so it immediately sends the HTTP request to the server. But if you look at your code, at that point you have not yet written anything to the output stream, so you are actually trying to send an empty request, and that's why you are getting an `EOFException`.

Try doing it in two steps instead. First, get the output stream, write to it and close it. Then get the input stream and read from it.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6036712/1464763).

Comment: i changed those statements and still the same problem. `dis.available()=0` i found out

Comment: Plase post your latest code and the complete stack trace of the error.

Comment: updated the code and added the output and stack trace.
take a look at it and let me know my mistake. thank you

Comment: Does it reach the server? Do you see something in the server's log?

Comment: 10.0.0.9 - - [06/Feb/2014:00:00:03 +0530] "POST /project/projectservlet HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.0.0.9 - - [06/Feb/2014:00:16:18 +0530] "POST /project/projectservlet HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 
this is what i got on log. 200 code means ok right?

Comment: In the servlet, try reading and closing the input stream before getting the output stream. That's all I can think of...

Answer (score 0):

Close OutPutStream in servlet after servlet work is completed.